# We would like Wikitravel links to auto-expand in our chat room just like Wikipedia links do.

Tags: feature-request, chat, hyperlinks

Dear Stack Exchange development programmer computer science engineer IT hackers.

If one day you think we're big and mature enough to give us a cool feature of our own that other Stack Exchange sites don't have, here is one we would like which ought to be very simple since it ought to work just like a standard feature.

There is a wiki for travellers running on MediaWiki software at [wikitravel.org](http://wikitravel.org/en/Main_Page) and since our SE site is also about travel we reference it a lot.

But you know how when you paste a Wikipedia link into a chat room on its own line it expands into the first bit of the article with a photo? It would be lovely to have the exact same happen when posting a wikitravel link too.

What do you think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've added basic handling for this; for some reason the images are being a bit fiddly (despite the API *appearing* to support them, it isn't playing ball). We'll see if we can get those in due course.

Comment: Thanks! That was very fast!

Comment: @marc - any chance of [taking a look a this request](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1213/101) - very similar...

Comment: @MarkMayo sure thing